# i want to get data from the transaction hash i tried many codes at last i am getting boxes in the output

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix, contract-debugging, hash

1) First, I got the input

`console.log(web3.eth.getTransaction('0x725fc75264726f409793164e336e7d5ed35df8d2be469a0cc1a3a8cc4756b9b9').then((i) => console.log(i) ))`;

2) I manually pasted the input from the data,  in  both abi encoder and toAscii methods

```
console.log(abiDecoder.decodeMethod("0x0b3ee5dc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000119fbd8f9c700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000036d64760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");

 console.log(web3.utils.toAscii("0x0b3ee5dc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000........................."))
```

my output

```
>åÜ@ûØùÇmdv
```

but I have inserted

> "mdv",1233

my solidity code

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract hotelbooking {

struct hotel {
  string HotelName;
  uint256 BookingNumber;
}

hotel[] HotelBookings;

function  HotelTranscation(string _HotelName,uint256 _BookingNumber) public {

  hotel memory temphotel = hotel(_HotelName,_BookingNumber);
  HotelBookings.push(temphotel);
}

    function GetHotelBooking(uint _num) public view returns(string, uint256) {
        return (HotelBookings[_num].HotelName, HotelBookings[_num].BookingNumber);

    }
```

1) Everything is working fine when using index for getting the data.

2) But I want to get the data by using transaction hash, please help me.

3) I have used online compiler remix to develop the code.

Comment: Are you sure, your input for `uint256 _BookingNumber`  parameter was '1233'? I'm getting 1211111111111 for this input.

Answer (score 0):

You need ABI of you contract to get data correctly. This code snippet might help. I'll add more details when I have some time.

```
const abi = require('ethereumjs-abi');

function checkDecoding() {
  const abi = require('ethereumjs-abi');
  let params = ["mdv",1233]
  let contractABI = [ 'string', 'uint256']
  let encoded = abi.rawEncode(contractABI, params)
  let data = Buffer.from(encoded)
  let decoded = abi.rawDecode(contractABI, data)
  console.log(`Decoded: ${JSON.stringify(decoded, null, '  ')}`)
}
```

Comment: Thanks 

but i want to get data from transcationhash   which we get from the etherscan